# изменение css определенного diva

Tags: javascript, jquery

на странице есть дивы с .item , внутри них 2 дива, .news-text-area и .news-img-area, как с помощью jqery, если в одном или нескольких блоках .item , див .news-img-area не пуст, прибавить padding к .news-text-area который находится рядом с ним в блоке .item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
...   
value = 999;
$(".news-img-area").each(function(){
    var size = $(this).text().length;
    if (size > 0){ 
        var targetElement = $(this).parent().children(".news-text-area");
        if (targetElement !== undefined)
        {
            targetElement.css( "padding", value);
        }
    }
});
...
```